# Building an array dynamically based on an array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like to build an array based on an array except that column data in my array does not match column headings.
How can I put in front the right owners of collone with the right data?

Currently I get this table, except that the data of items 03 and items04 should not be displayed in column R2018_04 but in column R2020_03

```
Kpi      | R2018_04 | R2019_B2 | R2020_03 | No Data |
---------|----------|----------|----------|---------|
Items01  | 0        | 0        |          |         | 
Items02  | 11       |          |          |         |  
Items03  | 4        |          |          |         |  
Items04  | 4        |          |          |         |     
Items05  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |   
Items06  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |   
Items07  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |  
Items08  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |     
Items09  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |       
Items010 | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |
```

Here is the array used which is stored in the $ tab2 variable

```
$tab2 = [
  "head" => [
    "R2018_04" => "R2018_04",
    "R2019_B2" => "R2019_B2",
    "R2020_03" => "R2020_03",
    "No Data" => "No Data",
  ],
  "Item01" => [
    "R2018_04" => [
      "response" => true,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
    "R2019_B2" => [
      "response" => true,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
  "Item02" => [
    "R2020_03" => [
      "response" => false,
      "value" => 11,
    ],
  ],
  "Item03" => [
    "R2020_03" => [
      "response" => false,
      "value" => 4,
    ],
  ],
  "Item04" => [
    "R2020_03" => [
      "response" => false,
      "value" => 4,
    ],
  ],
  "Item05" => [
    "No Data" => [
      "response" => 2,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
  "Item06" => [
    "No Data" => [
      "response" => 2,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
  "Item07" => [
    "No Data" => [
      "response" => 2,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
  "Item08" => [
    "No Data" => [
      "response" => 2,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
  "Item09" => [
    "No Data" => [
      "response" => 2,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
  "Item10" => [
    "No Data" => [
      "response" => 2,
      "value" => 0,
    ],
  ],
];
```

Here is the code that I did to arrive at the result of the wrong table

```
// count number of head 
        $nbHead = count($tab2['head'])-1;

        // build the table
        $output = '<table style="border: 1px solid #333; width:100%; font-family:calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">';
        $output .= '<thead><tr>';
        $output .= '<th style="text-align:center; width: 30%; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">Kpi</th>';
        foreach ($tab2['head'] as $value) {
            $output .= '<th style="text-align:left; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">'.$value.'</th>';
        }
        $output .= '</tr></thead> ';

        foreach ($tab2 as $key => $value) {

            if($key != 'head'){

                $output .= '<tr>';
                $output .= '<td style="text-align:left;">'.$key.'</td>';

                foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                    // get status with css
                    switch ($v['response']) {
                        case 1:
                            $status = 'Pass';
                            $kpi_value = $v['value'];
                            $style = "green";
                        break;
                        case 0:
                            $status = 'Fail';
                            $kpi_value = $v['value'];
                            $style = "red";
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            $status = 'N/A';
                            $style = "orange";
                        break;
                        default:
                            $status = 'N/A';
                        break;
                    }

                    if($status == 'N/A'){
                        for ($i=0; $i < $nbHead ; $i++) { 
                            $output .= '<td style="text-align:center;"> - </td>';
                        }
                        $output .= '<td style="text-align:center; background-color:'.$style.'">'.$status.'</td>';
                    }else{
                        $output .= '<td style="text-align:center; color: white; background-color:'.$style.';">'.$kpi_value.'</td>';
                    }
                }
                $output .= '</tr>';
            }
        }
        $output .= '</table>';
        //exit();
        return $output;
```

The data of the array is generated dynamically, so the column of the array can vary according to the data reported by the array.
Here is the expected array with the given array.

```
Kpi      | R2018_04 | R2019_B2 | R2020_03 | No Data |
---------|----------|----------|----------|---------|
Items01  | 0        | 0        |          |         | 
Items02  | 11       |          |          |         |  
Items03  |          |          |  4       |         |  
Items04  |          |          |  4       |         |     
Items05  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |   
Items06  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |   
Items07  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |  
Items08  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |     
Items09  | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |       
Items010 | -        | -        | -        | N/A     |
```

Comment: I've made a runnable version on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/R2buM

Comment: Basic idea would be to not do the inner loop over the $value, but to loop over the header data again, and while doing so access the corresponding elements of the $value, if they are set. Only thing that makes this a bit harder, is your apparent differentiation between “No Data”, and fields that are not set - do you need it in exactly this way? (I mean, that Items02 : R2019_B2 is simply “blank”, whereas Items05 : R2018_04 is explicitly set to a `-`)

Comment: Inside an item, if `No Data` is set, does that mean none of the others (R2018_04, …) will ever be set at the same time?

Comment: And where does the status come into play, Pass/Fail? That does not appear in your examples at all.

Comment: Your expected result seems to be wrong as well, why does Items02 have the 11 show up in the R2018_04 column? Items02 had the 11 under the `R2020_03` key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, I think your current desired result is wrong, the placement of the 11 for Items02 seems to make little sense. Assuming that actually belongs into the R2020_03 column, here’s how I would approach this.

The innermost loop over the data, gets replaced with a loop over the headers, `$tab2['head']`. That way, you will have no problem generating the right *amount* of table cells, no matter how many entries the current item actually contains. The *key* of `$tab2['head']` will then be used to check if the item has the corresponding element set, and create the output accordingly. This solution also assumes, that if the `No Data` entry is present, that also means it will be the first and *only* entry for the item.

```
// build the table
$output = '<table style="border: 1px solid #333; width:100%; font-family:calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">';
$output .= '<thead><tr>';
$output .= '<th style="text-align:center; width: 30%; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">Kpi</th>';
foreach ($tab2['head'] as $value) {
    $output .= '<th style="text-align:left; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">'.$value.'</th>';
}
$output .= '</tr></thead> ';

foreach ($tab2 as $key => $value) {

    if($key != 'head'){

        $output .= '<tr>';
        $output .= '<td style="text-align:left;">'.$key.'</td>';

        foreach($tab2['head'] as $colKey => $colValue) {
            if(isset($value['No Data'])) {
                if($colKey != 'No Data') {
                    $output .= '<td style="text-align:center;"> - </td>';
                }
                else {
                    $output .= '<td style="text-align:center;"> N/A </td>';
                }
            }
            else {
                $style = 'transparent'; // defaults for
                $kpi_value = '';        // “empty” cells
                if(isset($value[$colKey])) {
                    switch ($value[$colKey]['response']) {
                        case 1:
                            $kpi_value = $value[$colKey]['value'];
                            $style = "green";
                        break;
                        case 0:
                            $kpi_value = $value[$colKey]['value'];
                            $style = "red";
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            $style = "orange";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $output .= '<td style="text-align:center; color: white; background-color:'.$style.';">'.$kpi_value.'</td>';
            }
        }
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
}
$output .= '</table>';
```

That would get you the following table, as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6L5weubj/

---

I left out your Pass/Fail status here, because as I commented, from your examples it is not apparent when and where that is supposed to have an effect or show in the result. If that status is of importance to you and also needs to be output in the table or affect the style somehow, then try and add it in again yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this return, it is exactly the expected table, sorry for the error on my example, I changed the css for the color of alert is well positioned